# Building a KML in Python

Tags: python, loops, csv, kml

I'm trying to build a KML file from a csv to display points in Google Earth, but I'm having a few small issues...
Firstly, I can get it to build the file, but the csv has six sets of coordinates in it and the kml only displays two (which is actually one displayed twice). I've obviously got the loop wrong, but can't figure out how.
Secondly, the placemark that is generated ['53.66018'],['-1.94925'] displays in the ocean somewhere, when it should be in Manchester (UK)
I'd be grateful for any and all help. Thanks in advance!
Here's the Python code-

```
import csv
import os
fp = "C:\\Python27\\test.csv"
file = open(fp)
lines =file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    fields = line.split(';') #semicolon seperated
    LCID = fields[0].split() #splitting
    CID = fields[1].split()
    LAC = fields[2].split()
    NET = fields[3].split()
    LAT = fields[4].split()
    LON = fields[5].split()

    print 'LCID' #print splitted
    print ("CID: " + str(CID))
   # print ("LAC: " + str(LAC))
   # print ("NET: " + str(NET))
   # print ("LAT: " + str(LAT))
   # print ("LON: " + str(LON))

f = open('C:\\Python27\\csv17kml.kml', 'w')
fname = "testing_Actions"
#Writing the kml file.
f.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n")
f.write("<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>\n")
f.write("<Folder>\n")
f.write("   <name> Op Example </name>\n")
for row in lines:
    f.write("   <Placemark>\n")
    f.write("       <ExtendedData>\n")
    f.write("           <Data name='CID'>\n")
    f.write("               <value>\n")
    f.write("               " + str(CID) +"\n")
    f.write("               </value>\n")
    f.write("           </Data>\n")
    f.write("           <Data name='LAC'>\n")
    f.write("               <value>\n")
    f.write("               " + str(LAC) + "\n")
    f.write("               </value>\n")
    f.write("           </Data>\n")
    f.write("       </ExtendedData>\n")
    f.write("       <Point>\n")
    f.write("           <coordinates>" + str(LAT) + "," + str(LON) + "</coordinates>\n")
    f.write("       </Point>\n")
    f.write("   </Placemark>\n")
f.write("</Folder>\n")
f.write("</kml>\n")
print ("File Created. ")
f.close
file.close()
```

And here's the data in the csv:

```
LCID;CID;LAC;NET;LAT;LON

26599;26599;3569;23410;53.66018;-1.94925;
26599;26599;3569;23410;53.66018;-1.94923;
26599;26599;3569;23410;53.66019;-1.94922;
26599;26599;3569;23410;53.66019;-1.94919;
26599;26599;3569;23410;53.66018;-1.94919;
26599;26599;3569;23410;53.66018;-1.94917
```

Here are the header and footer parts I added...

```
def write_header(output_file):
    return
"""<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>\n
    <Folder>\n
    <name> Op Example </name>\n"""   

def write_footer(output_file):
    return
"""</Folder>\n")
        </kml>\n
print ("File Created. ")
f.close
file.close()"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the mistake pointed out by Blutack, you read through the input file, but you are not storing the coordinates anywhere.

If you split your code into more modular functions, it is a lot easier to reason about the functionality and to check if they work correctly.

Also you are working too hard by doing everything manually. There is a module for reading [csv files](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), manually handling the closing of files is obsoleted by context managers and if you want multi-line-strings, you can use triple quotes. Additionally, if you want to fill in some values into what amounts to a template, you can use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) with named substitutions to make it more readable.

So that's what I came up with: (using [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to get a more comfortable representation of each line)

```
from collections import namedtuple
import csv

location_info = namedtuple('location_info', 'LCID,CID,LAC,NET,LAT,LON')
input_filename = "input.csv"

def write_header(output_file):
    pass  # left as an excercise

def write_footer(output_file):
    pass  # also left as an exercise

def get_kml(location_info):
    return """    <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData>
            <Data name='CID'>
                <value>
                    {CID}
                </value>
            </Data>
            <Data name='LAC'>
                <value>
                    {LAC}
                </value>
            </Data>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>{LON},{LAT}</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>""".format(**location_info._asdict())

with open(input_filename, 'r') as input_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=';')
    print next(csv_reader)  # gets rid of the header line
    all_locations = (location_info(*line[0:6]) for line in csv_reader)  # the slicing is due to the trailing ;

    with open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
        write_header(output_file)
        for location in all_locations:
            output_file.write(get_kml(location))
        write_footer(output_file)
```

Comment: That looks a lot cleaner. I didn't have enough energy to rewrite the code as idiomatic python!

Comment: Thanks very much to you both! I thught the triple """s were only for commenting. (I'm now to Python). I've amended the header and footer parts, but now get the error 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\testMap4.py", line 47, in <module>
    for location in all_locations:
  File "C:\Python27\testMap4.py", line 43, in <genexpr>
    all_locations = (location_info(*line[0:6]) for line in csv_reader)  # the slicing is due to the trailing ;
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file' Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Did you get the indentation correct? Indentation is meaningful in python and input_file is only open within the block starting `with open(input_filename) as input_file:`

Comment: Ah yes, sorry... When I ran it, it complained about the indenting, so I changed it about. Having changed it back, I'm now getting 'NameError: name 'f' is not defined'. I thought it might have needed to be 'output_file.write(get_kml(location))' but then I get the error 'NameError: name 'get_kml' is not defined'... I'm stuck in a loop of my own ignorance :) Can you help?

Comment: I wrote the output part without checking. I've fixed it.

Comment: At least I got something right today ;D I'm still getting the 'NameError: name 'get_kml' is not defined' error though.. .

Comment: I've fixed my answer, you need to rename `get_location` to `get_kml`

Comment: Thanks so much for your attention Thomas, that did the trick :)

Comment: I'd love to, but I don't have the reputation points to allow that... Sorry. While I still have you on the line, so to speak, it's not writing the header and footer components to the kml file... I added to the original post the header and footer parts I wrote. I'd greatly appreciate any pointers. Sorry for my endless stream of stupid questions and thank you for your patience :)

Comment: Also not enough reputation to move that to chat... ;) you're generating the header and footer in your functions and return the strings, but you're not writing them to the file. Returning the strings is a good idea, easier testable. But to allow you to finish, replace the `return` with `output_file.write`.

Comment: Brilliant, that's done the trick! It's creating a nice, well laid out kml now that points to the right place on the map :) As Columbo might say though... 'One more thing...' :D In my original question I mentioned that only one placemark is showing, though there are six in the test.csv file. I would have thought the 'all_locations = (location_info(*line[0:6]) for line in csv_reader)' line would have looped through them. How do I get multiple placemarks to show? (The files this will have to work on eventually will have lots, hundreds even...) Thanks again Thomas, you're a true gent!

Comment: You did loop through the file, overwriting all your variables every time. After the loop, only the last one was still available. The line you pointed out in my code generates a `location_info` instance per line of your input. This way you can iterate over all_locations when creating the output.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#point

The coordinates in the KML file should be in lon, lat order (which seems a bit counterintuitive!). 
You need to flip them.

```
f.write("           <coordinates>" + str(LON) + "," + str(LAT) + "</coordinates>\n")
```